How to prevent users from accessing wp-admin and wp-login.php for everyone except the administrator?
tell me how you can prevent users from accessing wp admin and wp-login.php for everyone except the administrator? That is, it should work before and after authorization in the system.
I found one code and it works fine before and after authorization. But this code also prevents the administrator from entering the control panel.
<?php 
function custom_login_redirect() {
    // Check if the current URL contains "/wp-admin" or "/wp-login.php"
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin') !== false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-login.php') !== false) {
        // Redirect to your custom login or registration page
        wp_redirect(home_url('/your-custom-login-page')); // Replace with the actual URL of your custom login page
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_login_redirect');
?>

How can I make sure that only users with administrator rights have the opportunity?

"it should work before and after authorization in the system" - how would before work? Aren’t they anonymous users just like everyone else? Also, WordPress’s admin area is already locked down, just make sure to have a good strong password (preferably one you cannot remember), and consider MFA.
